# APNs messages not always received

Tags: ios, apple-push-notifications

I am sending APNs messages from a server via Apple's enhanced protocol. I can see that almost all messages are acknowledged without errors, but in trials, my experience is that the messages do not always arrive.

About ~10% of messages are lost, with no idication from either the OS or the app that they've been received. In some cases I have been able to find the token and payload and resend successfully, so it appears like these are intermittent failures.

Does anyone have a similar experience when using APNs? Any ideas on how to improve the service so that I don't lose so many messages?

Comment: This could be related to the ADN outage they are having. Is this happening in Sandbox or Production?

Comment: how did you verify that all messages are acknowledged? I thought there will be no response if message are sent successfully?

Answer (score 0):

I'm seeing the same failure rate for push notifications in production.
I don't know of any ways of improving the value, and it seems that this behavior is to be expected-> Quote from [Apple Doc](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/NetworkingInternet/Conceptual/RemoteNotificationsPG/Chapters/ApplePushService.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40008194-CH100-SW1):

> Important: Delivery of notifications is a “best effort”, not guaranteed. It is not intended to deliver data to your app, only to notify the user that there is new data available.

It might be worth tracking what devices did receive the messages, and retry for the ones that did not receive anything.